# Fetch Out Of Sequence ORA-01002

Tags: plsql

Hi can anyone check with below and help me. I am getting fetch out of sequence error and ref cur values not inserting into object type.

```
object (x,y,z)
type a is table of object

procedure a_procedure(a out a_ref cursor, b out b_ref cursor)is

x a := a();

begin
b_procedure(ref cursor)
if ref cursor%found then
loop
a.extend;
a(a.count) := object(null,null,null)
fetch ref cursor into a(a.count).x
                    a(a.count).y
                    a(a.count).y;
exit when b_refcur%notfound;
end loop;
end;
/
```

Context:  The values are not fetching from b_procedure's ref cursor. I want to fetch ref cursor value from another procedure and that value fetch into object.

Comment: what's inside your b_procedure? What's the ref_cursor that is passed?

Answer (score 0):

```
begin
b_procedure (ref_cursor);
if ref_cursor%is open then
fetch ref_cursor into r`enter code here`ecord;
collection_type.extend;
collection_type(collection_type.last):=object(record.value1),
                                             (record.value2),
                                              ...etc);
end if;
end;
/
```